# Get the number of rows per tenant of several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, rowcount

Let's say I have 2 tables: `Tenants` and `Wargles`. `Wargles` has a Foreign Key towards `Tenants` called `TenantId`. If I want to get number of wargles per tenant, I can do this:

```
SELECT t.Id as TenantId, count(w.Id) as WargleCount
FROM Tenants t
JOIN Wargles w ON w.TenantId = t.Id
GROUP BY t.Id
```

Now, let's say I have another table, `Fiddles`, that, as `Wargles` has a FK towards `Tenants`. How can I add another column to the query above, so I get the number of wargles and the number of fiddles for each tenant?

I tried with this:

```
SELECT t.Id as TenantId, count(w.Id) as WargleCount, count(f.Id) as FiddleCount
FROM Tenants t
JOIN Wargles w ON w.TenantId = t.Id
JOIN Fiddles f ON f.TenantId = t.Id
GROUP BY t.Id
```

But this won't work, since it would give me the same number both for WargleCount and FiddleCount, the product of the rows from both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two subselects

```
SELECT t.Id as TenantId, 
       (SELECT Count(1) FROM Fiddles F WHERE F.TenantId = T.Id) as FiddleCount,
       (SELECT Count(1) FROM Wargles W WHERE W.TenantId = T.Id) as WargleCount
  FROM Tenants t
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient method is probably to use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT t.Id as TenantId,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Wargles w
        WHERE w.TenantId = t.Id
      ) as WargleCount, count(f.Id) as FiddleCount
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM Fiddles f
       WHERE f.TenantId = t.Id
     ) as FiddleCount
FROM Tenants t;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of indexes on `Wargles(TenantId)` and `Fiddles(TenantId)`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, as extendable solution, I would recommend Scalar Function usage.

```
/* SAMPLE DATA ARRANGE */
CREATE TABLE Tenants (Id INT, Title NVARCHAR(5)) ; INSERT INTO Tenants VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B') , (3, 'C');
CREATE TABLE Wargles (Id INT,TenantId INT);INSERT INTO Wargles VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1) , (3, 1) , (4, 2), (5, 2) , (6, 1), (7, 3) , (8, 3);
CREATE TABLE Fiddles (Id INT,TenantId INT);INSERT INTO Fiddles VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1) , (3, 1) , (4, 2), (5, 2) , (6, 2), (7, 3) , (8, 2);
```

The Function

```
/*NEEDED CODE*/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetTenantsNo ( @Id AS INT , @Tb AS INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT = 0;

    IF (@TB = 1)
        SELECT @Result = COUNT(*)
        FROM Wargles
        WHERE TenantId = @Id
    ELSE
        SELECT @Result = COUNT(*)
        FROM Fiddles
        WHERE TenantId = @Id

    RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

Select Statement

```
SELECT Id AS TenantId
    ,dbo.ufnGetTenantsNo(Id, 1) AS WargleCount
    ,dbo.ufnGetTenantsNo(Id, 2) AS FiddleCount
FROM Tenants
```